# Remove selected html element from start tag to end tag with values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to parse HTML and want to remove all `&lt;select>...&lt;/select>` from string which is from TextArea1 and want to show output (Plain Text) in TextArea2. Code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />
    <textarea id="TextArea2" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />
    <input id="Submit1" onclick="parsehtml()" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <script>
        function parsehtml() {
            let value = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value
                .split('\n')
                .filter(item => item.startsWith('<span>'))
                .map(item => item.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/ig, " ").trim()).join(' ')

            document.getElementById("TextArea2").value = value
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my TextArea1 I have code like:

```
<span>Span 1</span>
<select>
<option>opt 01</option>
<option>opt 02</option>
</select>
<span>Span 2</span>
<select>
<option>opt 11</option>
<option>opt 12</option>
</select>
```

I'm getting output like

```
Span 1 Span 2
```

Code is working if I have all in a seperate line. But not working if I have all codes in a single line eg.

```
<select><option>opt 1</option></select><span>Span 1</span>...
```

I want to remove all `&lt;select>` element with all of its values from start tag to end tag. and want to output from dynamic generated HTML code

```
Hello <select class="..." onchange="..."><option>opt 01</option><option>opt 02</option></select><span>World</span> Hello <select><option>opt 11</option><option>opt 12</option></select> <span>Again</span>

//need output like below

//Hello World Hello Again
```

Comment: Um, you can't really parse html with regex. In case if you want to just remove selects, you can use lazy matching and replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `div`, put `TextArea1`'s content into that `div` as HTML, use Javascript's DOM support to remove `select`s and copy the `innerHTML` into `TextArea2`.

```js
    function replaceSelect() {
        var div = document.createElement("div"); //created a div
        div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value; //copied the source text as HTML into the div
        for (let select of div.querySelectorAll("select")) select.remove(); //Lopped select tags inside the div and removed them
        document.getElementById("TextArea2").innerText = div.innerHTML; //Copied the result into the target
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="TextArea1"><select><option>opt 1</option></select><span>Span 1</span>...<select><option>opt 1</option></select><span>Span 2</span></textarea>
<textarea id="TextArea2"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Remove Select" onclick="replaceSelect()">
```